# Can I change how controls are drawn in windows?

Tags: windows-11, dialog

Can I do something so that I can actually see some controls in a dialog box? Namely, ScrollBars are near invisible, and active tab in TabControl should be highlighted better. High contrast themes are better, but XP/win7 looks best to me.

It seems that themes from windows store are concerned only about wallpapers and sounds, buy I may be wrong.

**Update**: High contrast themes are good enough for a dialog resource editor, which probably uses its own paint method to draw controls anyway. So I'm now interested in theming controls in all the other apps - if that is possible.

[invisible scrollbars in visual studio resource dialog editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhqt.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Move your mouse over the control bar and it becomes visible. Thin control bars have been around for quite a few years now.

Comment: Which Windows theme or customization are you using ?

Comment: @John Moving my mouse is not good enough, especially in a dialog editor when I'm moving one control with the mouse already - I can't see the dimensiones of all the other controls.

Comment: @harrymc well, the default one, whatever came with Windows. I just switched it to Dark mode.

Comment: Not all applications have a good support for Dark mode.

Comment: You might show a better screenshot of what you are dealing with.

Comment: @John if the colors were "normal" (and not just gray) you would have no problems knowing that those are two scrollbars. There is no better screenshot, that's how the editor paints them. The only things visible are the scrollbar thumbs (darker gray).